# How to setup Moq with Callbacks?

Tags: callback, moq

Ok, I have started to look at Moq, so this is a noob question.
I have followed the [quick guide](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart), and I am trying to setup a callback to return a specific model:

```
void Main()
{
    var resultData = new MyModel();
    var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();

    mock.Setup(x => x.Register(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(new MyModel { Name = "Test" })
        .Callback<MyModel>((data) => 
        {
            resultData = data;
        });

    var parameter = "123";
    var result = mock.Object.Register(parameter);
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    MyModel Register(string code);
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I get this exception on the call:

> ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted
>   to type 'UserQuery+MyModel'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `T` in the `Callback<T>` method should match the parameter type of the method being `Setup`.  In other words, Moq is letting you set a callback method with the same parameters as the method being mocked.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here.  If you're just trying to save the return `MyModel` object from your mocked method, do this:

```
var returnedModel = new MyModel { Name = "Test" };
mock.Setup(x => x.Register(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(returnedModel);
```

If you're trying to create a `MyModel` with the given `string` parameter, do this:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Register(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string data) => new MyModel { Name = data });
```